# how to make textView clickable and collect information about clicked data?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

i had data set which are retrieve from sqlite database and the data will display by using textView.

this is code

```
ContactDatabase onbOfContactDatabase=new ContactDatabase(getBaseContext());
Cursor allcontact= onbOfContactDatabase.showData();

TextView  t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String dbString="";

allcontact.moveToFirst();

do {
    dbString+=allcontact.getString(allcontact.getColumnIndex("name"));
    dbString+="\n";

    t.setText(dbString);

} while(allcontact.moveToNext());
```

The output of this code like

```
new text
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
```

i want all data make clickable and how to know who data is clicked?
plese help this is argent.

Comment: Use listview instead of textview

Answer (score 0):

Change the TextView to a ListView then set onClickListener for the ListView, then with that set 
`String output = listview.getselecteditem(position);`